# Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on null values.(using combo box)

Tags: c#, mysql, box

Hi I have nulls in a table that I will use to populate a combo box. I am not sure how to do this. When I run the below code I get the error:

> Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on null values.

I need help and I'm new to mysql

the code :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
    string Query = "SELECT * from database.check WHERE patientname IS NOT NULL";
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string namethestore = myReader.GetString("namethestore");
            string checkername = myReader.GetString("checkername");
            this.textBox65.Text = namethestore;
            this.textBox66.Text = checkername;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a check of Sytem.DBNull.Value before you assign the value to the Text property of your textbox, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431835/dbnull-if-statement

Comment: First, where exactly do you get the exception, and secondly, won't simple null check make the trick?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When one or more of your fields contains a NULL (DBNull.Value) you cannot use `GetString` on them.
You need to check if they are null using the IsDBNull method and choose what value you want to put in the textbox instead. Usually it is an empty string

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
    string Query = "SELECT * from database.check WHERE patientname IS NOT NULL";
    using(MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    using(MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase))
    {
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            using(MySqlDataReader myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int namePos = myReader.GetOrdinal("namethestore");
                int checkerPos = myReader.GetOrdinal("checkername");
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string namethestore = myReader.IsDBNull(namePos) 
                                          ? string.Empty 
                                          : myReader.GetString("namethestore");
                    string checkername = myReader.IsDBNull(checkerPos) 
                                          ? string.Empty
                                          : myReader.GetString("checkername");
                    this.textBox65.Text = namethestore;
                    this.textBox66.Text = checkername;
                }
           }
      }
}
```

I suggest also to use the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) around the disposable objects. This will ensure a proper closing and disposing when you don't need them anymore, also in case of exceptions.....

Comment: i tried but i got  an error : 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'IsBNull' and no extension method 'IsBNull' accepting a first argument of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It was a typo. The method name is IsDBNull.