# C# method gives System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, mysql

Hello im makeing an application for school where we need to work with databases. Now i have one last error that i cant get to fix. I have a combobox where you can select a soccer league. Then the clubs of that league appear in a listbox. Based on what club you select the players from that club appear in an different listbox.

Now i have a method that takes the average cards given to the defenders of that club. If i first select a league, club, player and then change the league and select a club from the different league my application crashes.
it gives me this error

> System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

here is my code for the method im talking about.

```
public string GetGemKaart(string selecteditem)
        { //label gem kaarten per verdediger (club stat.)
            using (MySqlConnection mysqlcon = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                MySqlCommand mysqlCmd = mysqlcon.CreateCommand();
                mysqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT (AVG(GeleKaarten) + AVG(RodeKaarten)) FROM Spelers, clubs where clubs.naamClub = '" + selecteditem + "' and spelers.idclubs = clubs.idClubs and spelers.positie = 'V'";
                mysqlcon.Open();
                int returnvalue = (int)Convert.ToInt32(mysqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
                return returnvalue.ToString();
            }
        }
```

and the code where i call this method:

```
private void ListboxClubs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        { // Update de kampioenschappen en opgericht label wanneer een club is geselecteerd en laad spelers
            if (listboxClubs != null && listboxClubs.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                string SelectedItem = listboxClubs.SelectedItem.ToString();
                //laad spelers
                List<Spelers> allspelers = db.Getspelers(SelectedItem);
                listboxspelers.ItemsSource = allspelers;
                //clubstatistieken

                lblkampioen.Content = "Aantal kampioenschappen: " + db.Getkampioen(SelectedItem);
                lblopgericht.Content = "Opgericht: " + db.Getopgericht(SelectedItem);
                lblgemdoel.Content = "Gem. Doelpunten Per Aanvaller: " + db.GetGemDoel(SelectedItem);
                lblgemkaart.Content = "Gem Kaarten Per Verdediger:" + db.GetGemKaart(SelectedItem);

            }

        }
```

Comment: I would assume that one of your fields is returning NULL instead of a value. Which line throws the error, exactly? That should give you a clue. Then you need to write some code to [check for DBNull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431835/dbnull-if-statement) before attempting to assign the result to another variable.

Comment: Try making you integers accept null by adding a question mark :  int? returnvalue = (int?)Convert.ToInt32(mysqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM Spelers, clubs WHERE ...` No, you don't want to write cross join, it's deprecated since 25 years. use [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) instead

Comment: I might be wrong, but if I remember well, you don't have to open the connection (`mysqlcon.Open();`) when you are doing `using (MySqlConnection mysqlcon = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)) { .. }`